# Method type overloading

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like this:

```
public static void Initialize<T>(T obj) where T : BaseClass
{
  SetDefault(obj);
}

private static void SetDefault(AInheritedFromBaseClass thing)
{
  // do something
}

private static void SetDefault(BInheritedFromBaseClass thing)
{
  // do something
}
```

So everytime I initialize the obj it is directed to the correct method. Is that possible?

I can not implement those methods on the classes it self, because they are external classes. So basically I'd like to have a gereric way to initialize them they way I want to. I'd like to avoid something like this:

```
if (obj is TypeA)
{
  ClassThis();
} else if (obj is TypeB)
{
  CallThat();
}
//etc.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dynamic`:

```
public static void Initialize<T>(T obj) where T : BaseClass
{
    SetDefault((dynamic)obj);
}
```

It will force your method overload selection happen on runtime instead of compile time.

Answer (score 0):

If they're external classes and you need to modify the way they are initialized, I'd go with something like the [Adapter pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html), instead of coming up with workarounds.

Also, your solution will crash at runtime if you ever like adding a third `BaseClass` implementation and forget to add another `SetDefault` overload. You shouldn't rely on that.